# C# implementation of MS5637 sensor with I2C on IoT

Tags: i2c, windows-iot, c#

I've been looking at implementing a library to use the MS5637 Barometric Sensor.  I would like to have a C# implementation that I can use on Raspberry Pi 2 running Windows IoT and using the I2C interface.

I can write it myself, but don't want to unnecessarily reinvent the wheel.  If any of you have a C# library that accomplishes this, please let me know.

Comment: Well... I couldn't find what I needed, so I wrote it myself.  Please see answer below for implementation written by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok,

I've implemented a C# class that talks very nicely to the MS5637 sensor using I2C and Windows 10 IoT.

In order to use the code below, you need to add as references:
Universal Windows
Windows IoT Extensions for the UWP
Windows Mobile Extensions for the UWP
Microsoft.NetCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform (NuGet)

Here's the code.. Enjoy...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.I2c;

namespace MS5637
{
    /*
        This class was written by:  Curtis V. Harrison - curtiscode@gmail.com
        You can use it all you want, just be nice and keep my name at the top of the file.

        Sample code for using the 'Windows.Devices.I2c.I2cDevice' can be found at:
        https://ms-iot.github.io/content/en-US/win10/samples/I2CAccelerometer.htm

        Data Sheet for MS5637 can be found at:
        http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1756129.pdf
    */

    /// <summary>
    /// MS5637Device class usage
    /// This class is simple to use:
    /// 
    /// 1.  Create an instance using the default no param constructor, or provide a Slave Address
    ///     The constructors will initialize the sensor and prepare it data retrieval
    /// 2.  Call 'GetTemperaturePressure()' and you will receive a 'TemperaturePressure' object.
    ///     Temperature is in 'farenheit' and pressure is in 'mbars';
    /// 3.  Use the 'Temperature' or 'Pressure' properties of the TemperaturePressure object as you like.
    /// 4.  Whenever you need updated Temperature or pressure, follow instruction 2 above..
    /// </summary>
    public class MS5637Device : IDisposable
    {
        private const int MS5637_SLAVE_ADDRESS = 0x76;
        private static readonly byte[] MS5637_RESET_COMMAND = {0x1E};
        private static readonly byte[] MS5637_COEFFICENTS_COMMAND = {0xA0};
        private static readonly byte[] MS5637_COEFFICENTS_END_COMMAND = {0xAE};
        private static readonly byte[] MS5637_HI_RES_TEMPERATURE = {0x5A};
        private static readonly byte[] MS5637_HI_RES_PRESSURE = {0x4A};
        private static readonly byte[] MS5637_DATA_READ_COMMAND = {0x00};

        private I2cDevice Sensor { get; set; }
        private List<ushort> Coefficients { get; set; }
        private double Temperature { get; set; }
        private double Pressure { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor requires no arguments.
        /// This constructor assumes a SlaveAddress of 0x76 for the MS5637 sensor.
        /// Constructing this object will initialize it and prepare it for data retrieval.
        /// </summary>
        public MS5637Device() : this(MS5637_SLAVE_ADDRESS)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor requires a single byte 'SlaveAddress' as an argument.
        /// The typical SlaveAddress for the MS5637 sensor is 0x76.
        /// Constructing this object will initialize it and prepare it for data retrieval.
        /// </summary>
        public MS5637Device(byte slaveAddress)
        {
            Init(slaveAddress);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Call this method whenever you want to get current Temperature and Pressure values.
        /// This method returns a 'TemperaturePressure' object which in turn has a Temperature and a Pressure
        /// property.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public TemperaturePressure GetTemperaturePressure()
        {
            try
            {
                GetD1D2();
            }
            catch
            {
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, 500);
                Sensor.Write(MS5637_RESET_COMMAND); //Reset Device
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, 10);
                Debug.WriteLine("BOOM !!!  CRASH !!!  RESET !!!");
            }

            return new TemperaturePressure(Temperature, Pressure);
        }

        private void Init(int slaveAddress)
        {
            InitSensor(slaveAddress).Wait();

            byte[] command = new byte[1];
            Sensor.Write(MS5637_RESET_COMMAND); //Reset Device
            SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, 10);

            Coefficients = new List<ushort>();
            byte[] coefficent = new byte[2];

            for (command[0] = MS5637_COEFFICENTS_COMMAND[0];
                command[0] < MS5637_COEFFICENTS_END_COMMAND[0];
                command[0] += 2)
            {
                coefficent[0] = 0;
                coefficent[1] = 0;
                Sensor.WriteRead(command, coefficent);
                Coefficients.Add((ushort)(coefficent[0] << 8 | coefficent[1]));
                SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, 50);
            }

            GetTemperaturePressure();
        }

        private async Task InitSensor(int slaveAddress)
        {
            var settings = new I2cConnectionSettings(slaveAddress) {BusSpeed = I2cBusSpeed.FastMode};
            string aqs = I2cDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            var dis = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs);
            Sensor = await I2cDevice.FromIdAsync(dis[0].Id, settings);
        }

        private uint ConvertBytesToInt32(byte[] data)
        {
            uint value = ((uint)data[0] << 16) | (uint)data[1] << 8 | data[2];
            return value;
        }

        private void GetD1D2()
        {
            byte[] d1PressureBytes = new byte[3];
            Sensor.Write(MS5637_HI_RES_PRESSURE);
            SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, 30);
            Sensor.WriteRead(MS5637_DATA_READ_COMMAND, d1PressureBytes);
            uint D1 = ConvertBytesToInt32(d1PressureBytes);

            byte[] d2TemperatureBytes = new byte[3];
            Sensor.Write(MS5637_HI_RES_TEMPERATURE);
            SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => false, 30);
            Sensor.WriteRead(MS5637_DATA_READ_COMMAND, d2TemperatureBytes);
            uint D2 = ConvertBytesToInt32(d2TemperatureBytes);

            CalculateTemperaturePressure(D1, D2);
        }

        private void CalculateTemperaturePressure(uint D1, uint D2)
        {
            var dT = D2 - Coefficients[5] * Math.Pow(2, 8);
            var offset = Coefficients[2]*Math.Pow(2, 17) + (dT*Coefficients[4])/Math.Pow(2, 6);
            var sensitivity = Coefficients[1]*Math.Pow(2, 16) + (dT*Coefficients[3])/Math.Pow(2, 7);
            var t1 = (2000 + (dT * Coefficients[6]) / Math.Pow(2, 23)) / 100;
            //Assume temperature is > 20 celsus inside somebody's home
            var t2 = 5 * Math.Pow(dT, 2) / Math.Pow(2, 38);
            t1 -= t2;

            Temperature = t1 * 1.8 + 32;
            Pressure = (D1*sensitivity/Math.Pow(2, 21) - offset)/Math.Pow(2, 15)/100;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the internal Sensor object when Dispose() is called on this object.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (Sensor != null)
            {
                Sensor.Dispose();
                Sensor = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is a simple container class which allows for a Temperature and a Pressure
    /// to be stored and passed.
    /// </summary>
    public class TemperaturePressure
    {
        public double Temperature { get; set; }
        public double Pressure { get; set; }

        public TemperaturePressure(double temperature, double pressure)
        {
            Temperature = temperature;
            Pressure = pressure;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best place at the moment to look for any supporting device libraries like that would be at the [Microsoft's IoT Github page](https://github.com/ms-iot/).

If you cannot find a C# implementation anywhere then its likely there is none yet. You would have to find a C implementation, like for Arduino and try and see how its configured, any caveats, etc and try to port it as you suggest.

It would be brilliant if you could get the IoT Git, do your implementation in somnething like "samples/I2CBarometer" - following the conventions (directories, file names. [Similar to the Compass Sample, using an interface to allow various chip 'drivers' to be implemented](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/I2CCompass/CS/Sensors)) and do a pull request. You may have to follow some other steps for doing PR. It is likely somebody may accept it, comment on it, etc. Even if takes a while, your code will be there for other to use, in the right place and hopefully indexed by search engines to be found.

If you need more help feel free to comment below to notify me (I am not associated with MS but willing to help the community grow). Maybe first get your base C# code going then it can be converted into a Sample and Interfaced ready for Git.